# How to prevent highlight a input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code,

```
<input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; height:24px; width:300px; font-size: 12px;  padding: 0 0 0 10px;" placeholder="Full Name" >
```

How to prevent highlight the inputfield when input?

Comment: highlighting the field or the content of the field? should the content still be editable?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by highlight?

Comment: Click on the comment box in this page. Do you see that, when the cursor appears, comment box border color change to gold color. It calls highlight (I found in many sites, people has named it as highlight).

Answer (score 2):

try something like this...

```
input {
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: I noticed that "outline:none" was used in your stylesheet, so: sort of irrelevant, but also important to note: PLEASE don't overuse outline:none in your stylesheets, as it's really important for accessibility reasons. http://outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 1):

***try (and please, do not write style inline):***

css:

```
#inp {
font-family: Tahoma; height:24px; width:300px; font-size: 12px;  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
#inp:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

html:

```
<input id="inp" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" >
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

Outline is the border which shows up when the element is focused. If you don't want any change in the style even when the text input is active, use this

```
outline:0;
```

Comment: Outline:0 works, but it's better form to use outline:none. Just obeying the specs. :) Oh, and just a reminder: I don't think that it's a good idea to overuse outline:none in your stylesheets, as it's really important for accessibility reasons. http://outlinenone.com/